# Attribute names being truncated during extraction

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, fields-attributes

I have 30-40 raster layers and each raster has approximately 40 columns. The attribute/column names are very long, and the beginning of each column name is the same. During the extraction process, these column names are truncated, losing a lot of information regarding the variable/column name.

I am, for example, using **[Extract multi values to points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000002s000000)** to extract from .tiff to a shapefile point feature class.

For example:

`vpr_Avg_1970to2010_m01Jan_800m` is truncated to `vpr_Avg_19`
`vpr_Avg_1970to2010_m02Feb_800m` is truncated to `vpr_Avg_20`

.... `vpr_Avg_21`

Is there any way to keep the entire column name?

I'm working with ArcMap 10.1

Comment: from what and to what file type are you exracting

Comment: What are the exact steps in your "extraction process"?

Comment: "Extract multi values to points". Extracting from .tiff to a point feature class shapefile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shapefile format cannot support column names longer than **10** characters (a limitation of the dBase format).  If you converted to an enterprise geodatabase (ArcSDE) table the limit would be **31** characters (**30** in Oracle).  File geodatabase supports **64** character column names.

Comment: yay shapefile \o/ :)

Comment: Try to use file geodatabases and/or SDE unless a shapefile is ultimately required.
http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0309/files/9reasons.pdf